# UITableView disappears when switching from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, uitableview, landscape, portrait

hey there, I am creating an app that requires me to add tables in a particular page. The page should
be in landscape mode but the application in portrait. I've figured out the switching i.e from portrait
to landscape and back to portrait [homepage(portrait) -> tablePage (landscape)] and vice versa. The problem is the table view keeps reducing in size i.e the first time I am able to see the whole table, but when I go back to the home page and come back to the tablePage I just see half the table, it's like as if the table view gets cut off. Again I go back to the homepage and come back to the table page I don't see the table at all, i.e the whole table disappears. Please help.

Comment: i think the table is moving up, not reducing in size. what are you doing in your controller to show the view in landscape? have you designed the xib in landscape or turning it programmatically??

Comment: // rotate the view and re-align it:
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform =
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 90 * M_PI / 180 );

[self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform]; 

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

The above code is what I have in my ViewWillAppear function. I am
loading a nib file that is landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Everything works fine in iOS 4.3 simulator, but one single UITableview disappeared in iOS 5 in landscape mode. I solved this by simply dropping another UIView on my view and moved the UITableView into that.

Looks like a bug in iOS 5 to me. Let's hope, Apple will fix it soon.